# AngularJS dynamically add elements to ng-repeat template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array called 'variables' that I turn into a table.

```
<tr ng-repeat="variable in variables">
  <td>
    <textarea ng-model="variable.extras" ...>{{variable.extras}}</textarea>
  </td>
```

I then have a function numberOfRowsForChoiceVariable that looks at variable.extras and determines how many lines it has, doing things like removing blank lines, etc...  So now on the next <td> element I want to have as many <select> elements as returned by the call to numberOfRowsForChoiceVariable(variable).

So if they put 4 lines into variable.extras, then I want to display 4 select elements inside the next <td>

I'm thinking I need to use some type of $watch() to enable that, but I'm not sure how to use that within the ng-repeat scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Use Case

Please let me know if I have misunderstood your question. Here's what I understand from your question.

1. User enters text into the textarea
2. System counts the number of lines
3. Number of lines will create that number of select element. [**edit**: updated solution to meet this requirement]

### Solution

You can use a filter to create a list from your line counting.

#### Controller

Based on your requirements, this controller uses regular expressions to count the number of lines. I haven't tested this on a Unix system, but it works fine on Windows. The `lines` function will return the number of lines from a given string input.

```
function ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.variables = [{extras: ""}, {extras: ""}, {extras: ""}];

    $scope.lines = function (input) {
        if (angular.isString(input)) {
            return input.split(/\r?\n/).length;
        }
        return 0;
    };
}
```

#### Filter

A filter is required to create a temporary array of a given length. This is a common component from functional programming.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.filter('range', function () {
    return function (input, total) {
        total = parseInt(total);
        input = Array.apply(null, Array(total))
             .map(function(value, index) {
                 return index;
             });
        return input;
    };
});
```

#### View

Using this view, the `<select>` can be dynamically created next to the textarea. I've shortened the variable names so it could fit within this screen, but don't do this, it's bad form.

```
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller="ctrl">
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="v in variables">
            <td>
                <textarea ng-model="v.extras">
                    {{v.extras}}
                </textarea>
            </td>
            <td>
                 <select ng-repeat="n in [] | range:lines(v.extras)">
                 </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

#### Demo

You can access a demo from this [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MrRampage/CRg2c/).